# Precompile handlebars template with node results in empty file

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to precompile an handlebars template with node.
I installed node but when i compile the template what i get is only opening the handlebars file in my editor!

This is che prompt cmd i use after navigating in the folder where the template is:

```
$ handlebars lista.handlebars -f lista.js
```

What is the correct way to do it?

---

**Solution**: I had the handlebars.js file inside the same directory of my templates so the prompt cmd opened that file instead of following the compile instruction!

Comment: is that mispelled extension a keying error?

Comment: yes, corrected! but it was not the reason. I tried with the node prompt but i got this message: 'Unable to open template file 'lista.handlebars'

Comment: What OS? Whats the current working directory and is the file located relative to that working directory?

Comment: windows 7. the file is located inside the directory which looks like: e:\web\websites\client\html\assets\js\